# Finding the content in a row

Tags: java, html

The row contains

row number  --  name surname -- instructor name--   E

```
</tr>
<tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
<td height=20 class=xl6429100 align=right width=28 style='height:15.0pt;
border-top:none;width:21pt'>row number</td>
<td class=xl8629100 width=19 style='border-top:none;border-left:none;
width:14pt'>&nbsp;</td>
<td class=xl6529100 width=137 style='border-top:none;border-left:none;
width:103pt'>name</td>
<td class=xl6529100 width=92 style='border-top:none;border-left:none;
width:69pt'>surname</td>
<td class=xl7929100 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>instructor name</td>
<td class=xl8129100 style='border-top:none'>grade</td>
```

I want to retrieve only one row from this html file to control my own grade. I get the source of the html by using java but now how can I reach the row that I want? I will find the surname first. In this part of the table how can I reach the grade coloumn?

here is my code;

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class staj {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL staj = new URL("http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~sekreter/SummerTraining/2014G/CS399.htm");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(staj.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    String grade;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
        if(inputLine.contains(mysurname))   
        //grade = WHAT? 
    }
    in.close(); 
}
```

And also, is using java efficient and appropriate for this aim? Which language would be better?

Comment: What HTML parser are you using?

Comment: Chris Martin I am not using HTML parser. That's good idea. I was planning to parse manually by searching my name/surname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely use `Jsoup` library to extract what you need from HTML document - http://jsoup.org/

I've created a sample code that demonstrates an example of extracting data from the table you provided in a description: https://gist.github.com/wololock/15f511fd9d7da9770f1d

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String url = "http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~sekreter/SummerTraining/2014G/CS399.htm";
    String username = "Samet";

    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    Elements rows = document.select("tr:contains("+username+")");

    for (Element row : rows) {
        System.out.println("---------------");
        System.out.printf("No: %s\n", row.select("td:eq(0)").text());
        System.out.printf("Evaluator: %s\n", row.select("td:eq(4)").text());
        System.out.printf("Status: %s\n", row.select("td:eq(5)").text());
    }
}
```

Take a look on this:

```
document.select("tr:contains("+username+")");
```

`Jsoup` allows you to use jquery-like methods and selectors to extract data from html documents. In this example selector you extracts only those `tr` elements that contain given username in nested elements. When you have a list of those rows you can simply extract the data. Here we use:

```
row.select("td:eq(n)")
```

where `:eq(n)` means **select n-th td element nested in tr**. Here is the output:

```
---------------
No: 85
Evaluator: Buğra Gedik
Status: E
---------------
No: 105
Evaluator: Çiğdem Gündüz Demir
Status: E
```